# Run Powershell command on remote PC with different credentials

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2007

I need to figure out how to remotely run an Exchange Management Shell command on an exchange server that has it installed.

Answer (score 2):

This code shows how you can open a WSMan connection to a remote machine using whatever credentials you want:

```
PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(someUserName, someSecurePassword);

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://targetmachinename:5985/wsman"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", credential);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;

using(Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))           
{
   ... use runspace here ...
}
```

Now, that will connect up a bare-bones PowerShell instance. If you want to connect to an Exchange ready PowerShell instance, you can specify the Exchange `shellUri` to WSManConnectionInfo instead and you shouldn't even have to worry about adding the snap-in:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://targetmachinename:5985/wsman"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
```

Comment: Forgive me if  this is a stupid question. I understand what my URI is, but how do I determine the shell URI?

Comment: I'll update the answer.

Comment: How do I determine this exchange shell URI?

Comment: The above comment is a ridiculously good question that I can't find the answer to anywhere. This WSManConnectionInfo class really wants a uri which makes no sense, what's the uri for when it comes to powershell??? What is the shell? I don't understand why it's asking for this.